TypeScript infer object literal type while enforcing type of values on object?
I want to enforce all the values on an object literal be a certain type. However I want to be able to set any string key name. And then I want to infer the type of that object literal.
Here is an example:
type Fruit = 'apple' | 'banana' | 'pear'

const list = {
  eat: 'apple',
  save: 'banana',
  sell: 'pear',
}

type FruitKey = keyof typeof list

type FruitDetails = { [key in FruitKey]: Fruit }

const fruitDetails = list as FruitDetails

playgrund here
This example isn't quite right because it does not ensure each value is of type Fruit, I could add give: 'pizza' to the list and it would not compain.
I could define it like so:
const list: {[k in string]: Fruit} = {
  eat: 'apple',
  save: 'banana',
  sell: 'pear',
}

This will ensure only fruit are added but now I can no longer infer the keys for my FruitKey which now just becomes type string.
Is there a way to achieve this?

You can use satisfies probably
const myFruits = {
  eat: 'apple',
  save: 'banana',
  sell: 'pear',
  cook: 'pizza', //Type '"pizza"' is not assignable to type 'Fruit'.(2322)
} satisfies Record<string, Fruit>

type T = typeof myFruits //gives exact type

or if you prefer with a generic function it works well
const makeFruits = <T extends Record<string,Fruit>>(value: T)=>value

makeFruits({
  eat: 'apple',
  save: 'banana',
  sell: 'pear',
  make: 'pizza', //Type '"pizza"' is not assignable to type 'Fruit'.(2322)
})


Thanks a lot, i figured out how to do it myself using the generic function approach. But the satisfies is a new concept to me. That is very cool. Thanks a lot!

nice, yea either work fine

I can only figure out how to do it if I wrap it in a function like so:
type FruitMap<K extends string> = {
  [key in K]: Fruit
}

function makeFruitMap<K extends string>(l:FruitMap<K>):FruitMap<K> {
  return l
}

